# What ANOVA is appropriate in identifing before and after treatment?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, biostatistics

Each patient is received a treatment and researcher conducted a survey to measure certain metrics. The survey with the same questions and measurement methods is conducted to the same patients *before treatment, 1 month after treatment, 3 months after, 6 months after, 1 year after, 2 year after.*

1. Want to test if patient's metrics change before and after treatment;
2. Till which time point could we observe significant changes in patients' metrics? (for example, we can conclude that after 1 months of treatment, there is no significant change, however, the change tends to become significant after one year of receiving the treatment.)

*Which ANOVA test is appropriate to answer the above questions?*
*If I want to break down the patient by gender and age and answer the above questions, what change in terms of ANOVA test?*

Some sample data is provided. There is missing data in metrics and unbalance in gender group.

```
PatientID   Treatment   Gender  Age metrics0    metrics1    metrics2    metrics3    metrics4
1   a   F   57  91  89  98  101 103
2   a   M   38  81  69  88  94  97
3   a   M   27  100 76  79  92  98
4   a   M   51  116 107 0   110 112
5   a   F   58  106 83  104 108 111
6   a   M   66  78  70  90  123 108
7   a   M   54  61  59  64  65  
8   a   M   32  88  85  101 120 122
9   a   F   76  103 98  104 110 118
10  a   M   33  80  66  75  85  115
11  a   F   48  105 91  99      119
12  a   M   46  90  80  93  105 103
13  a   F   34  110 102 113 117 0
14  a   M   45  98  91  97  109 118
15  a   F   39  121 112 106 132 145
16  a   M   65  99  90      107 113
17  a   M   30  86  69  83  98  101
18  a   M   37  94  82  81  146 126
19  a   F   43  91  81  0   90  117
20  a   M   54  144 116 117 140 130
21  a   F   49  98  109 115 136 152
22  a   M   20  94  84  103 123 0
23  a   M   31  99  89  84  99  114
24  a   M   54  127 128     121 147
25  a   F   49  93  97      114 
26  a   M   29  132 102 104 114 118
27  a   F   50  112 84  94  111 
28  a   M   52  66  55  73  88  86
29  a   M   53  114 113 117 111 105
30  a   M   27  73  73  0   105 94
31  a   F   33  125 106 114 126 111
32  a   M   49  117 99  107 119 124
```